# Migrating to SpringBoot 2 issue when using xml bean definition file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this code that requires to be migrated to SpringBoot2. Issue is that there are 2 bean definitions is in xml and one had to be injected based on the value of the arg in main method so @ImportResource annotation was not used to inject the xml.

What was used before:

```
ApplicationContext context = new SpringApplication(App.class,"some-xml-that-will-change-based-on-args[0]-value.xml").run(args);
```

This no longer works in SpringBoot2 because the constructor argument changed:

```
public SpringApplication(ResourceLoader resourceLoader, Class<?>... primarySources) {

}
```

What I have tried:
i. Tried using SpringApplicationBuilder but it does not inject the xml.

Comment: You should consider defining the beans in `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: Yea, we are planning to update the code at a later date but is there a solution to the immediate question?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing much about your environment, but you should be able to initialize your application this way:

```
ApplicationContextFactory applicationContextFactory =
        ApplicationContextFactory.of(() -> new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("some-xml.xml"));

SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplicationBuilder(DemoApplication.class)
        .contextFactory(applicationContextFactory).application();

springApplication.run(args);
```

If your application-context XML files are not on the classpath you may also have a look at FileSystemXmlApplicationContext. For your use case you could also consider to implement custom ApplicationContextFactories which take care of loading the correct XML file.